# Program that passes STDIN to STDOUT with color codes stripped?

Tags: colors, pipe, filter

I have a command that produces output in color, and I would like to pipe it into a file with the color codes stripped out. Is there a command that works like `cat` except that it strips color codes? I plan to do something like this:

```
$ command-that-produces-colored-output | stripcolorcodes > outfile
```

Comment: It might be a bug that a program produces colored output even then it's output is redirected to a file _and_ doesn't provide an option to switch it off.  I'd expect any program that colors it's output to check `isatty(stdin)` before doing so.  Mind to share what is that program?

Comment: pass it through `cat` - quick test I ran `grep --color=auto myusername /etc/passwd` gives me my username in red with white text elsewhree.  `grep --color=auto myusername /etc/passwd | cat` gives me plain white text

Comment: That's not a solution. It only works because `grep --color=auto` avoids producing colored output when standard output is not a terminal. I'm talking about a command that unconditionally outputs color codes. (As alex points out above, such behavior is arguably a bug, but sometimes we need to work with imperfect software that we can't easily fix ourselves, and that's what this question is about.)

Comment: Possibly relevant https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output

Comment: Reinforcing Ryan's post: `grep --colour=always myusername /etc/passwd | cat` keeps the username in red.

Comment: [ansi2txt](https://superuser.com/a/1513099/642842)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You'd think there'd be a utility for that, but I couldn't find it.  However, this Perl one-liner should do the trick:

```
perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g'
```

Example:

```
$ command-that-produces-colored-output | perl -pe 's/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g' > outfile
```

Or, if you want a script you can save as `stripcolorcodes`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  s/\e\[?.*?[\@-~]//g; # Strip ANSI escape codes
  print;
}
```

If you want to strip *only* color codes, and leave any other ANSI codes (like cursor movement) alone, use

```
s/\e\[[\d;]*m//g;
```

instead of the substitution I used above (which removes all ANSI escape codes).

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to another answer (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped#4531), this regex was pulled from `Term::ANSIColor`. Acknowledge your sources, please!

Comment: acknowledge your sources!

Answer (score 33):

#### [Remove color codes (special characters) with GNU sed](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed)

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

Or

#### Strip ANSI escape sequences in Python

Install [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) python package (`pip install colorama`). Put into `stripcolorcodes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import colorama, fileinput, sys;
colorama.init(strip=True);

for line in fileinput.input():
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Run `chmod +x stripcolorcodes`.

Comment: Didn't try python, but the sed version doesn't strip all colors. (I didn't test exhaustively, but it left some background colors intact, so I went with the faster perl option.)

Answer (score 23):

If you can install the [Term::ANSIColor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aANSIColor) module, this perl script works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Term::ANSIColor qw(colorstrip);
print colorstrip $_ while <>;
```

Comment: That's actually where I got that color-codes-only regex.  But installing a whole module just for that one regex is a bit much.

Comment: Meh, if you set up cpanm correctly, it installs the module in about 5 seconds.

Comment: There is no need to write the script to the file. Just pipe into: `perl -mTerm::ANSIColor=colorstrip -n -e 'print colorstrip $_'`

Answer (score 11):

If your system has access to [NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.org/) you could install the following Node package, [`strip-ansi-cli`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/strip-ansi-cli).

```
$ npm install -g strip-ansi-cli
```

You can then run your command like so:

```
$ command-that-produces-colored-output | strip-ansi > outfile
```

Comment: NodeJS is a huge dependency, when there are solutions that can use languages and tools already present in most systems.

Comment: Also, this is the slowest solution listed (see [here](http://blog.vmchale.com/article/strip-benchmarks)) and you probably *will* notice the difference.

Comment: It's worth noting that all this module does is replaces all matches of the regex `string.replace(ansiRegex(), '')` which is defined here https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/blob/main/index.js.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ command-that-produces-colored-output | ansifilter
```

... and if necessary, `(dnf, ...) install ansifilter`

Answer (score 3):

This sed command did it for me:

```
sed -r "s/\\^\\[(\\[[^@-~]+[@-~]|[0-9@-_]|%@)//g"
```

Example:

```
$ command-that-produces-colored-output | sed -r "s/\\^\\[(\\[[^@-~]+[@-~]|[0-9@-_]|%@)//g" > outfile
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest version of `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ac](https://hub.darcs.net/vmchale/fastcat) for this. It should be faster than anything listed above (though `perl` and `sed` should be decent). Here's an example:

```
curl -s wttr.in/LA | ac -s
```

As a disclaimer: the color filtering functionality was written by me.