# Is it possible to uncolor STDIN before writing it to file?

Tags: colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

Is there a utility which uncolors colored output? Something like the `uncolor` utility in the example below:

```
$ ./colored_output | uncolor > plain.txt
```

The aim is to remove characters like "`[0m[32m`" and "`[0m[1m`" which get additionally output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
./colored_output |
    sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}((;[0-9]{1,3})*)?)?[m|K]//g" > plain.txt
```