# How can i redirect the output to a file when the program is build with ncurses library

Tags: files, io-redirection, top, ncurses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

If we redirect output to file in this pattern `top >> somefile.txt`, we get lot of garbage value in the output. But for `top` there is batch (`top -b -n1 >> somefile.txt`) option where the file output is as desired. In case of programs like `nethogs` there is no such options. Is there is good way to output in such case.

Comment: I would say that the best thing to do is to write to the authors of nethogs requesting they add a mode similar to top -b.

Comment: I created a comment saying this is not a duplicate, but when I try to edit the title of this question to express the real question it becomes "How to clean the output of an ncurses program?", which is clearly a duplicate. Voted to close.

Comment: for nethogs, may be these options are new? `nethogs -t` or `nethogs -b`, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296636/1422630) also

Answer (score 4):

You can also try filtering out the garbage yourself. For example, this would remove all the non-printable characters:

```
nethogs | sed 's,[^[:print:]],,g' >> somefile.txt
```

You can extend that as needed or take the opposite approach and only allow explicit non-garbage to come through, eg. (alphanumerics and punctuation):

```
nethogs | sed 's,[^[:alnum:][:punct:]],,g' >> somefile.txt
```

If the output is color coded, some extra work is needed to strip out the color escape strings.

Comment: you are cleaver I had almost given up then gave a couple last desperate google searches wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a good way, but sometimes setting the terminal can help.

E.g.,

```
TERM=dumb top
```

gets rid of most control characters.