# How to strip color codes out of stdout and pipe to file and stdout

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-script

I have a program that uses `printf` with some `tput` mixed in it and I'd like to pipe the output to stdout as well as a file. I'd prefer to use `sed` since I don't want any unnecessary dependencies on my script. Here's what I've got so far.

`printf "\n$(tput setaf 6)| $(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 7)Sourcing files...\033[m\n" | tee install.log`

The only issue with this is my log file is getting all of the color output as such...

`^[[36m| ^[(B^[[m^[[37mSourcing files...^[[m`

I'd like it to just have `| Sourcing files...`

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/22565

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, I'm trying not to use any of the perl scripts for now, and even the `sed` options don't seem to work.

Answer (score 14):

According to [removing colors from output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998978/removing-colors-from-output), you command should be:

```
printf "\n$(tput setaf 6)| $(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 7)Sourcing files...\033[m\n" |\
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g" |tee install.log
w/o "-r"
sed "s/\x1B\[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\(;[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\?\)\?[mGK]//g"
```

For convenience reasons you could also create an alias in `/etc/profile`

```
alias stripcolors='sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"'
w/o '-r'
alias stripcolors='sed "s/\x1B\[\([0-9]\{1,2\}\(;[0-9]\{1,2\}\)\?\)\?[mGK]//g"'
```

[Edit]

With the given output you can check this by yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($line=<DATA>) {
    $line =~ s/^[0-9a-f]+: //;
    while ($line =~ s/([0-9a-f]{2})(?=[0-9a-f]{2}| )//) {
      print chr(hex($1));
    }
}
__DATA__
0000000: 1b5b 316d 1b5b 3333 6de2 9aa0 2020 5761 .[1m.[33m... Wa
0000010: 726e 696e 673a 201b 2842 1b5b 6d4e 6f20 rning: .(B.[mNo
0000020: 2f55 7365 7273 2f61 7077 2f2e 6261 7368 /Users/apw/.bash
0000030: 2066 6f75 6e64 2e21 0a found.!.
```

The output:

```
$ perl checkerbunny|xxd
0000000: 1b5b 316d 1b5b 3333 6de2 9aa0 2020 5761  .[1m.[33m...  Wa
0000010: 726e 696e 673a 201b 2842 1b5b 6d4e 6f20  rning: .(B.[mNo 
0000020: 2f55 7365 7273 2f61 7077 2f2e 6261 7368  /Users/apw/.bash
0000030: 2066 6f75 6e64 2e21 0a                    found.!.

$ perl checkerbunny|stripcolors|xxd
0000000: e29a a020 2057 6172 6e69 6e67 3a20 1b28  ...  Warning: .(
0000010: 424e 6f20 2f55 7365 7273 2f61 7077 2f2e  BNo /Users/apw/.
0000020: 6261 7368 2066 6f75 6e64 2e21 0a         bash found.!.
```

Comment: the `-r` flag doesn't appear to work on Mac BSD, so I tried using `-E` would seems to be the most similar and it's still outputting in the log file as such...

`^[36m| ^[(B^[[m^[[37mSourcing files...^[[m`

It also comes back as `| ^[(BSourcing files...` on my Linux box.

Comment: please show us the output of your print cmd piped with `|xxd` and your `TERM` env. var.

Comment: `TERM` => `xterm`.

`0000000: 1b5b 316d 1b5b 3333 6de2 9aa0 2020 5761  .[1m.[33m...  Wa
0000010: 726e 696e 673a 201b 2842 1b5b 6d4e 6f20  rning: .(B.[mNo
0000020: 2f55 7365 7273 2f61 7077 2f2e 6261 7368  /Users/apw/.bash
0000030: 2066 6f75 6e64 2e21 0a                    found.!.`

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to do `printf "\n$(tput setaf 6)| $(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 7)Sourcing files...\033[m\n" | xxd`?

Comment: Could you compare the edited answer with your results.

Comment: it still vets me the same results, except that I have to change the `stripcolors` function because Mac OS X doesn't understand the `-r` option for the `sed` command.  I'm assuming you're on some sort of Linux distro?

Comment: according to [Extended regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html) there is luckily only different notation. Post is also updated. Should now be OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, this _does not_ work on OS X.

Comment: Both sed examples don't work in busybox sed.

Comment: I replaced the first `?` by `*` because otherwise my `ESC[00;34;47m` wasn't catched

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140255/218657) worked for me on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"  #credits to user55518
```

in an executable script somewhere in your PATH and name it something like `decolor`.

---

**Then you can easily use it as a color filter like this:**

```
$ something-that-generates-color | decolor
```

(I noticed someone else above found a similar thing above that was called `ansi2txt`.  I think that name is good, but it's harder to remember or find.  I like having the stub 'color' in it. And too bad this isn't just a standard GNU unix/linux utility.  It's very useful once you've colorized your ls, grep, tree, etc.)