# Strip color on OS X with BSD sed (or any other tool)

Tags: bash, sed, colors

I'm on OS X, which has a BSD version of `sed` (which I'm guessing is inferior to a GNU version on Linux), and [all the techniques for removing color on commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6141/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed#comment) did not work.  I tried replacing the `-r` switch (non-existent on OS X) with `-e`, but that didn't help.

Is there some reliable way I can remove color formatting codes on OS X?  Here's the command I'm running that needs color output stripped:

```
for concurrency in $(seq 1 50); do siege -f urls.txt -c $concurrency -t 5m >> results.csv ; done
```

and here's an example of trying to use `sed` to strip the color from the CSV output:

```
for concurrency in $(seq 1 50); do siege -f urls.txt -c $concurrency -t 5m | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" >> results.csv ; done
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With bash, this ought to pass sed appropriate arguments, I think:

```
sed $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g'
```

Or, more portably to other shells, you could try:

```
sed "s,$(printf '\033')\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"
```

Or just putting an escape byte directly into the string by typing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of typing `\x1b`.

Note, though, that this sed statement removes more than just color codes, potentially - it could match many control sequences starting with a CSI.  Search in page for "CSI" in [this](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.txt) to get an idea of what other control sequences it would remove (or possibly mangle).

Comment: The bash version worked without any adjustment needed: you deserve more upvotes than all the people on commandlinefu.com!