# Filtering the colored output of grep

Tags: grep, colors

I'm on OSX, but I suspect this doesn't make a big difference for this question.
In my `.bash_profile`, I aliased `grep` to get color outputs by default:

```
alias grep='grep --color=always'
```

I commonly run searches for content within files in my repositories in ways similar to:

```
grep --include=*.cpp -Ern . -e "(foo|bar)"
```

but I often want to further refine the results, typically piping with say `grep -v "colorbar"`.

The problem is that the second `grep` command then runs on the colored ouput, and doesn't seem to be able to match the exclusion patterns because of this.

Obviously I could run the first search without colors and then everything would work fine, but I would prefer to keep them if there is a way to work around this?

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111899/how-to-strip-color-codes-out-of-stdout-and-pipe-to-file-and-stdout . might also take a look at http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed

Comment: If you don't always want colors, why are you setting it to do that?  Do you often want the colors to be preserved through greps?  Perhaps you could just create an "uncolored" grep alias for those cases?

Comment: @EricRenouf As added with the edit, I'd prefer if the original matches could still be colored after the filter obviously.

Comment: @Dani_l Indeed this seems to work: `grep --include=*.cpp -Ern . -e "(foo|bar)" | sed -E "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | grep -v "colorbar"`  And it preserves the colors too! :) Should I close the OP then?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn , I am curious : How is color getting preserved ? Will not the grep fail if colors are still present ?

Comment: @Prem As you say, I would have expected that the colors are stripped by the sed, so I really have no idea why this works :)

Comment: @Sh3ljohn , I would say it will not work. It may look like working , but it may be skipping some lines or it may doing something unwanted. Your question remains unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and obvious answer is:

1. Change your alias to have `--color=auto` instead of `always`
2. Pipe your grep commands to your heart's content
3. Use an extra grep command at the end of the pipeline just to color the results you want colored, e.g.:

   ```
   grep --include=*.cpp -Ern . -e "(foo|bar)" | grep -v colorbar | grep -E -e "(foo|bar)"
   ```

This won't color your filenames and file numbers so nicely, however.

Another possible solution is much trickier, but still worth mentioning: You can use `pcregrep` and a single much fancier regex to handle all your filtering in one regex.

Comment: Yes, so matching without colors, filtering, and then matching with colors will work. It just feels a bit hacky, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn it does indeed.  You might consider running the `-v` test *first*, so you would only need two `grep` commands total.  There's another consideration about chaining `grep` commands you may not have considered, which is that the file names become part of the text examined by later grep commands.  Possible logic errors therefrom.

Answer (score -1):

remove the file /etc/profile.d/colorgrep*  With the newer version os linux they are forcing a alias for greg/egrep and  fgreg remove these files and it gets back to normal.

Comment: Wouldn't that break color usage in all `grep` invocations?  I'd also recommend against deleting files in `/etc` that a package manager has installed.