# Garbage in bash session log file. (using script command)

Tags: bash, special-characters, typescript

I tried to log bash session using:

```
js:/var/tmp # script -aqf /var/tmp/out
```

In `out` file I see, besides output, a lot of garbage. Instead of just whitespaces and new lines I see this, for example:

```
Script started on Tue Jul 14 14:17:57 2015
^[[?1034h^[[1m^[[31mjs-om:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[mpwd^M
/var/tmp^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[m^M
^[[1m^[[31mjs:/var/tmp # ^[(B^[[mexit^M
exit^M
```

I think the problem is with encodings. Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: If you just want to replay in your terminal the session : `more -v thescriptfile`. otherwise you'll need, as said below, to avoid your shell (... and commands) to create those escape codes, or find a proper sed to get rid of them (very complex afterwards, as some escape codes look widely different than the ones you show, and thus could take out huge chunks of the real output if you only have regexp trying to get rid of those ones)

Comment: It seems that with doing cat or more of script_file and manual coppying of text I can get session log without special characters. Of course it is not good to do like this permanently, but as a quick workaround it works

Comment: the easy way for the latter: open a putty session to the machine, cat the file, and right-click "copy all to clipboard". then paste into notepad (in case you added  the usually usefull "copy also also the  rtf in clipboard" option, pasting in notepad strips that out. the option is in other cases  usefull in keeping some color info when pasting to word or similar)

Comment: thanks, meanwhile where did you get -v option for more command ?

Comment: I always : `man somecommand`, before I use any command. Especially as similarly named commands have wildly different options on different systems (and sometime completely different actions too, such as "reset" which can either clear the terminal or reboot the host, depending on which system you are loggued into...)

Comment: Well, ok. I checked man more once again. There is no -v option for more in linux. Only v command which allows you to open editor from more.

Answer (score 2):

No the problem is not with encoding. You don't seem to follow the prerequisites for screen as mentioned in the man page:

```
 Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the type‐
 script file.  Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the
 screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal.
```

You have all kind of stuff probably resulting from a complex prompt. Set your prompt

```
PS1="$ "
```

to prevent that from writing garbage.

Comment: This excerpt from man page has nothing to do with prompt format. It means that using commands like vi, top etc(which manipulate display) will result in garbage, but not the format of your prompt. I see, it is obvious that with $ prompt there will be less control characters in log, but this is just workaround which is not suitable for me at all. And yes, now I see that this is not encoding issue. It's terminal control characters(incl color whitespaces etc) which might be deleted via script

Comment: Here is an example from my log ( just output from command ) : /var/tmp^M

Comment: That changing your prompt is not a solution is unclear from your question. Garbage in means garbage out and understanding where the garbage comes from make much more sense than blindly stripping jung from a file if you don't know where that junk comes from and/or if you will filter future versions. I would prefer the mess from happening in the first place.

Comment: Changing promt is not a deep dive into problem as well. It is even not a workaround as it leaves staff like /var/tmp^M. I use terminal, wich as I understand, require control characters to present session well(colors etc). And bash(I guess but I don't now for sure right now) appends those characters, and they a logged with payload. If you now how to leave those characters for terminal, and avoid them when writing to log, than it is good solution. Now I see only your half-working workaround and script.

Answer (score 1):

As well as fixing up your `PS1`, you may be able to persuade applications not to emit these non-printing characters by exporting a suitable value in the `TERM` environment variable.  The canonical one is probably `export TERM=dumb` at the beginning of your `script` session (or `TERM=dumb script <args>` when invoking).  Assuming that you create your `PS1` portably using `tput`, the latter may well work for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) appears to answer your question.

First you use script + after cleanse the typescript file of all escape sequences.