# Realtime print statements with tee in interactive script

Tags: rhel, sudo, python, pipe, tee

I have a program `long_interactive_script.py` which has thousands of `print` statements. I want to pipe the program through `tee` (or an alternative) so that I can save the output.

If I do

```
long_interactive_script.py | tee logfile.txt
```

Python puts its print statements in a 4K buffer,  causing me to get:

> nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, a whole lot of text!, nothing,
>   nothing, a sudo prompt in the middle of a word, nothing, nothing, a
>   whole lot of text!

In an attempt to avoid the buffer I tried:

```
unbuffer long_interactive_script.py | tee logfile.txt
```

But this causes my script to stop being interactive. So when the script breaks into a *sudo* prompt, it halts.

Note: I cannot simple `sudo` BEFORE running the script. The interactive script only requires `sudo` on some runs, and I don't want to ask for `sudo` when it isn't necessary.

More...

```
stdbuf -oL long_interactive_script.py | tee -a logfile.txt
```

works to some extent. I get all the desired data, but I also get this error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/coreutils/libstdbuf.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

Comment: "stdbuf -oL long_interactive_script.py | tee -a logfile.txt" works to some extent. I get all the desired data but I also get this error "ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/coreutils/libstdbuf.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored."

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting auxiliary comments.

Comment: Python should have a means to unbuffer a filehandle, such as `$fh->autoflush` in Perl, or `fconfigure stdout -buffering line` in TCL. This would avoid the complications imposed by `stdbuf`.

Comment: Interesting issue with stdbuf. Does a simple `stdbuf -oL true` produce the error? Also you might try `python -u long_interactive_script.py | tee -a logfile.txt`

Comment: @Brady, a simple `stdbuf -oL true` does not produce the error. Nor does something like `stdbuf -oL echo "hi" | tee /tmp/logfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Specify a zero-sized buffer for Python's standard output stream. You can do this by invoking Python with the `-u` flag, or with the following statement.

```
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
```

Comment: This works great in terms of getting all the output, but now my command line hangs even though long_interactive_script.py has finished executing. long_interactive_script.py also launches executable_A and executable_B. For some reason the command doesn't finish until I close the executables.

Comment: Unless the commands execute asynchronously (e.g. with `&` on a Unix shell), this is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds for buffering notwithstanding, that is why others use [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html), which captures all of the characters written to the terminal without interfering with interactive prompts.

The resulting `typescript` file is a little uglier than just redirecting to the standard output, but (assuming that your application was providing useful information in that mode), just trimming carriage return characters will suffice.

Beyond just carriage returns, there are editing characters to filter out.  See for example:

- [“render” textfile with carriage returns (^M) and save output to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238074/render-textfile-with-carriage-returns-m-and-save-output-to-file/296260#296260)
- [UNIX script command includes gibberish in export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441995/unix-script-command-includes-gibberish-in-export/39442028#39442028)

Comment: But I do still want it to print onto the screen

Comment: so I used script's -c option... didn't know it existed til now. Thanks!

Comment: The options are system-dependent (`-c` works with Linux, but not OSX).