# Email issue with output of bash script blcheck

Tags: bash, shell

Bash script blcheck from github format issues with emailing output

Console output displays correct, but when sent to email via mailx will on go as attachment, not to body.
    33%%  dnsbl.inps.de                                     ✓
    50%%  xbl.spamhaus.org                                  ✓

Output to file or email example:
16%%  dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net  ^MESC(BESC[m  16%%  dnsbl-.uceprotect.net      ✓ESC(BESC[m

Advise pls on how can I correct the format in file & email ?

CMD that's not sending to eamil body:

`sh blcheck -v xx.xx.xx.xx | mail -s "server-blcheck`date`" user@email.exampel`

script: https://github.com/IntellexApps/blcheck

---

After assistance of @john1024 & @cas & previous post [Removing Control Chars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) below cmd resolved issue.

```
CMD: ./blcheck-l -v xx.xx.xx.xx | perl -pe 's/\e([^[]]|[.*?[a-zA-Z]|].*?\a)//g' | col -b | mail -s "blcheck-l -v `date`" email@address
```

darko-poljak has submitted a pull request on github with a new option to make output friendly for non interactive use.
https://github.com/IntellexApps/blcheck/pull/2

Answer (score 2):

What you see are ANSI escape sequences.  In `blcheck`, they are used to change the colors of the text that is displayed *on the terminal*.  As you have discovered, they don't work in email messages.

To remove them permanently, edit the `blcheck` script with your favorite editor.  Find the lines:

```
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
CLEAR=$(tput sgr0)
```

And replace those lines with:

```
RED=
GREEN=
YELLOW=
CLEAR=
```

This will prevent `blcheck` from adding the ANSI sequences in the first place.

#### More flexible approach

It is possible to make the code work for either the terminal (ANSI) or a pipeline (no ANSI).  The following code tests to see if stdout is a terminal.  If it is, it sets the color variables to the required ANSI sequences.  If it is not a terminal, no ANSI sequences are generated.

```
RED=
GREEN=
YELLOW=
CLEAR=
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    RED=$(tput setaf 1)
    GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
    YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
    CLEAR=$(tput sgr0)
fi
```

Comment: You could also modify `blcheck` so that it uses colors if stdout is a terminal, and not use colors if stdout is a pipe.  e.g. `if [ -t 1 ] ; then RED=$(tput setaf 1) ; GREEN=... ; else RED= ; GREEN= ; ... ; fi`

Comment: @cas Good suggestion.  I added the code for that.

Comment: @Snowie Glad it worked.  (I cannot reproduce your email attachment issue: when I run the mail command that you provide, I get the output in the body of the email message.)  Separately, `blcheck` is a `bash` script.  So, for best results, you should call it as `bash blcheck ....`, not `sh blcheck ...` because, on many systems, `sh` is _not_ `bash`.

Comment: Hey John1024 - tried with bash & still arrives as an email attachment, which will drive me crazy as I just want to have a quick glance at email to make sure no blacklisting, the server is running Postfix MTA.

Comment: John1024 - wat MTA r u using?  I just tried on server with exim MTA & also as attached file.

Comment: are you using `bsd-mailx` or `heirloom-mailx`?

Comment: @Snowie, just add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line and make it executable with `chmod +x blcheck`. then you can run it with just `blcheck` if it's in the PATH or `./blcheck` if it's in current dir.

Comment: Thanks cas - centos 6 with postfix as MTA - mailx.x86_64  12.4-8.el6_6

Comment: @Snowie I am using bsd-mailx.  The server is exim.

Comment: Thanks John1024 &  cas - centos 6 with postfix as MTA - mailx.x86_64  12.4-8.el6_6 its from heirloom with a BSD licence.  Also tried on server running same malix ver but with Exim & end up with an attachment.  Another script I run pflogsumm.pl with the same mail cmd dumps it to email body OK.

Comment: @John1024, cas,  The reason its still mailing as attachment for me is the formatting, if I dump to file then remove Ctrl Char with:  cat myfile | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > myfile-fixed   I can then mail & as body.  Now I know why but need to figure out how to edit blcheck so it outputs in an mailx email friendly way for me.

Comment: @Snowie I downloaded `blcheck` as per your link.  After I removed the calls to `tput` (as per this answer), I have tried running it and I do not find any escapes (`\E`) or alerts (`\a`) in the output.  I tested this by running your perl script on the output, and then comparing with `cmp`: no difference.  Can you tell under what circumstances the modified script produces these characters?  Or, if not, can show me sample output that contains those characters so I can look in the source to try to see where they are coming from?

Comment: @john1024 this is with the tput removed " PTR resolves to mydomain.com
Matching against 3 blacklists
  16%%  dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net                            ^M  16%%  dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net                            ✓ "
 This ^M character I guess is the problem

Comment: @John1024 when I run script I use -v but either way the carriage returns ^M are there, when I output to file they can be seen & if send to email they r also there, not seen in output console of course.

Comment: @Snowie The `^M` character appears in the script several times in the form `\r`.  You can remove it by doing a search-and-replace in your favorite editor or by running sed 's/\\r/CR/g' blcheck >blcheck.new`.  However, `^M` is __not__ one of the characters affected by your perl script and it seems like an unlikely character to trigger a problem with text attachment.  Try removing it and see what happens but there is a chance that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Snowie It looks to me like `\r` probably only appears in the output if `verbose` is set.  It might be simpler to just try it without `-v`.

Comment: @John1024 with all the \r & tput removed it still fails if I use -v verbose  this char  can be seen in email attachment when using -v.  Sends to email body with no -v.  Also sends if I dump to file then run perl -pe 's/\e([^[]]|[.*?[a-zA-Z]|].*?\a)//g' | col -b then mail

Comment: @Snowie OK.  Let's try dumping to file, say `file1`.  Then run `perl -pe 's/\e([^[]]|[.*?[a-zA-Z]|].*?\a)//g' file1 | col -b >file2`.  Then run `diff file1 file2` and let's see where the differences really are.

Comment: OK done how do I best show u the diff outpu?

Comment: @John1024 comment box not enough to show u diff result.

Comment: @John1024 OK its working! - emailing to body.  blcheck edited with mod to #colors as above & all /r rmoved.  CMD that's working: ` ./blcheck-latest -v xx.xx.xx.xx | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b | mail -s "blcheck latest `date`" email@address`

Comment: @Snowie Glad it's working.  For future reference, it is considered good stackoverflow style for the OP (that's you, here) to respond to comments  by editing his question (where full formatting is possible) to add the additional information.  (Stackoverflow considers comments to be disposable and subject to deletion at any time.)

Comment: @John1024  thanks again John, I've had a go at tidy up edit of post.