# Top command output explanation (in embedded system)

Tags: linux, memory, command, top, busybox

Can someone please help me understand the output that I get from the top command? This is the point that the oom-killer is invoked and kills my main application. What exactly is under the VSZ and %VSZ? What is 502m304.5??[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output shows that `top` is printing some escape sequences that the terminal doesn't recognize. The bits where you see a blank followed by `[` followed by more garbage characters are escape sequences that work on most terminals; the first character of those sequences is the escape character, which your terminal prints as a blank. For example, `␛[7m` at the beginning of the title line starts inverse video, `␛[0m` stops inverse video, etc.

I'm not sure exactly what's going on with the STAT and VSZ column but it seems that top has printed some color-changing sequences there too (that's where the `m` is coming from), and they've been partially overwritten (top  is probably printing a `␈` character which does make the cursor go left so that the next character overwrites what was there).

With many programs, setting the `TERM` environment variable correctly is enough: it should indicate a terminal type that doesn't support any escape sequences. Make sure that you don't have a script that hard-codes a value of `TERM` somewhere. Try `TERM=dumb`. If you're using BusyBox, I think its `top` hard-codes escape sequences that work on most terminals, so you're out of luck. You could run it through a filter that removes escape sequences. Untested, but should work with BusyBox.

```
#!/bin/sh
script=$(printf 's/\033\\[[0-9;]*[A-Za-z]//g')
sed -e "$script" "$@"
```

(From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output/14707#14707) more complete Perl script)

Answer (score 0):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html:

**vsz** = 
"The size of the process in (virtual) memory in 1024 byte units as a decimal integer."

Comment: Thank you phk, however if you look at my output it has 502m304.5, what is that?