# col produces incorrect output

Tags: text-processing, terminal, escape-characters

I'm trying to post-process the output of `script` into a more readable form, similar to [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/294688), but I've noticed that `col` doesn't always work.

For instance,

```
$ cat -v uncolored 
foo^H^H^Hbfoo^H^H^Hafoo^H^H^Hr^M
$ col -bp < uncolored
baroo
```

Why doesn't `col -bp` output just `bar`? Where are the extra two `o`s coming from?

Comment: Is your terminal's backspace character `^M` or `^?`?

Comment: The backspace character is `^H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^H` in this case is backspace, AKA dec/hex 8 or oct 10 or `\b`. All it is doing is moving the cursor; take this example:

```sh
$ printf 'bravo\10\10X'
braXo
```

We have moved the cursor back 2, but we only wrote over one letter, the `v`. We didn't write over the `o`, so it remains. If you want to get rid of the rest of the letters, you have to overwrite them with something, usually a space character:

```sh
$ printf 'bravo\10\10X '
braX
```

http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#%5eH

Comment: Ah, the `uncolor` script from the other post removes all the `^[[K` controls which would've cleared the rest of the line, except `col` doesn't understand those either.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky workaround:

`sed -re ':b; s,[^\x08]\x08,,g; tb'`

- `:b`: Label `b`
- `s,[^\x08]\x08,,g`: Pair a non-backspace character with a backspace character and remove both
- `tb`: If the previous `s` directive did something, jump back to label `b`

Comment: A better workaround is https://github.com/RadixSeven/typescript2txt, which actually emulates a terminal and processes backspaces and ANSI escape sequences.