# Apply control charactes to file reddirect

Tags: bash, debian, control-characters

Tried various existing answers, but didn't find any which entirely works. This is one line example, and show how it fails, maybe some extra switch or step can solve this?

This is the content of file I am trying to save to txt file with control characters applied before making to disk: `fooo^H^H^H^Hbarr^H^H^H^H    ^H^H^H^Hok`

Best tool found til now is `col -b` but here is example where is fails.
I have tried:`cat mem.txt | col -b > mem2.txt` but result is `okrr` I don't know why it ignores those 4 spaces which should clean `barr` but it does.

Source problem is that I am trying to redirect clean log from `/usr/bin/time -f'%E' sudo memtester 2M 1` to file on disk but I am unable to clean it from junk from progress prints. This is only one program giving me this problems, I have several more so if this one has some mode not to print progress it will probably not solve my headaches.

EDIT [This sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449216/126210) works for `memtester` case, but not in general, so for now best solution is:

`| sed -re ':b; s,[^\x08]\x08,,g; tb' | col -b >`