# How to convert a string with hidden characters to a normal string

Tags: shell, text-processing

Does anyone have an idea on how to remove hidden characters from a string in the shell?

- This is an example :

  ```shellsession
  # echo $a;
  [root@localhost ~]#
  ```
- But when I "force" display of hidden characters it looks like this:

  ```shellsession
  # echo $a | cat -v
  [root@localhost ~]# ls ^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[Kpwd^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[Kls^H^[[K^H^[[Kpwd^H^[[K^H^[[K^H^[[K
  ```
- I want to delete hidden characters to have this output:

  ```shellsession
  # echo $a | cat -v
  [root@localhost ~]#
  ```

Comment: This is a minor variant on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/5132 .

Comment: Print the string to the terminal and then copy it back from terminal to your string.

Comment: You can also use tr command to delete everything except the class of characters you want. For example to keep only alphanumeric characters and get rid of everything else:  echo $a | tr -dc '[a-zA-Z-0-9]'

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to strip out the non-printing characters:

```
echo $a | sed 's/[^ -~]//g' | cat -v
```

Or to store it:

```
a=$(echo $a | sed 's/[^ -~]//g')
```

Comment: hello , thank for your answer but in the output it's give me "[@ ~]#  [[[[[[[[ [[[[[[[[[[[" i want to have the output without the hidden characters .

Comment: You have not tried out your answer.  Try it against the output of  `printf '[root@localhost ~]# ls \b\e[K\b\e[[K\b\e[Kpwd\b\e[K\b\e[K\b\e[K' ` to see how wrong it goes.

Comment: Ah, you also want to remove escape sequences in addition to non-printing characters. A second sed will accomplish that. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: ... or nm, see the post JdeBP linked in the comment to the main question.