# Redirecting output that spams terminal with carriage returns

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a command that creates very verbose output, on the order of hundreds of lines per second.  However, the command uses `\r` to overwrite the previous line of output, in a manner similar to a progress bar.  Occasionally it writes a newline to the terminal, which "bakes" the current output line.

When redirecting this output to a file, I get hundreds of megs of output - each line is written to the file, instead of being 'overwritten' when the carriage return occurs.

I understand this is the expected behavior, and that one way to solve it would be to make the program smarter, and realize it's being redirected to the file and not print this interactive status.  However, I can't modify this program.

Is there some way I can pipe/filter this output so that what ends up in the final output file is the same as what I would see if I ran it interactively on the terminal?

I've tried:

`spammy_cr_command | uniq`

... which outputs the same as without `uniq`

and also:

`spammy_cr_command | sed '/\r/d'`

... which deletes the "baked" lines that contain the newline character as well.

Comment: For more complex scenarios, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/5132 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cmd | sed -e 's/.*\r//' > file
```

This will replace all text on each line that is followed by a carriage return with nothing, leaving only the part of the line after the final carriage return behind. This is not *necessarily* the same as what would be left on the terminal, though, but it's a close approximation most of the time.

---

In particular, the case where a line is longer than its successor isn't handled. This program would give incorrect results:

```
printf 'abcdefg\rxyz\n'
printf '123456789\r\nxyz\n'
```

because what would be left behind visibly is

```
xyzdefg
123456789
xyz
```

but the `sed` would skip all the unerased characters as well and give

```
xyz

xyz
```

You can determine whether your program behaves like that or not. It's not uncommon for progress bars and the like to rest the cursor on the left-hand edge, which may not give the result you wanted.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you for sharing your `sed`-fu.

Answer (score 3):

For very primitive TTY-37 output, the `col` command solves this without the problems of `sed` mentioned in M. Homer's answer.  (For output that is not simple TTY-37 output, and contains terminal escape and control sequences, neither `col` nor `sed` are the tool for the job; but Stack Exchange has had a Q&A on *that* for almost eight years already.)

```
% (
printf 'abcdefg\rxyz\n'
printf '123456789\r\nxyz\n'
) | col -b
xyzdefg
123456789
xyz
%
```

Comment: This does not appear to work if the strings contain spaces.  If you replace "\rxyz" with "\rx z" in your example and run the command with and without `col -b` you get different output.  The sed answer does display the space.

Answer (score 0):

Something closer to the overwriting behaviour can be done with GNU awk:

```c
BEGIN { 
  RS = "[\r\n]"                   # split records on either CR or LF
  a = ""                          # variable to save the text for overwriting
} 
{
  a = $0 substr(a, 1 + length)    # save current line, add trailing part of saved text
} 
RT ~ /\n/ {                       # LF, time to print and reset
  print a;
  a = ""
}
```

Using Michael Homer's example:

```
~ awk 'BEGIN { RS="[\r\n]" } {a = $0 substr(a, 1 + length)} RT ~ /\n/ {print a; a=""}' foo
xyzdefg
123456789
xyz
```

GNU awk is needed for the `RT` variable, which contains the record separator text that matched the `RS` regex for that record.