# How to sort a column that also has color data?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sort, colors, escape-characters

I have a log file and I'm looking to sort according to response time, 4th field:

```
GET /api/user/john 200 0.194 ms - 7307
```

But it contains color tags, here's the output from `vi`:

```
^[[0mGET /api/user/john ^[[32m200 ^[[0m0.194 ms - 7307^[[0m
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why does your log file contain these? What tool is generating it? Can't you change that instead?

Comment: This is generated by PM2, and it's inserting the colors so sysadmin can see what's happening more easily. Probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Extract the field you want to sort on (typically with `cut`, `sed` or `awk`), and strip off its formatting escape sequences. You can find scripts for the second part in [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output). I'll use `uncolor` below to stand for one of these scripts.
2. Collate the result with the original (`paste`). Use a separator character that doesn't appear in the data to sort.
3. Sort.
4. Remove the sort key.

For example, if your fields are tab-separated:

```
<input-file.txt cut -f 4 | uncolor |
paste - input-file.txt |
sort |
cut -f 2-
```

Comment: `uncolor` was all I needed, I can now simply do `tail server.log | uncolor | sort -g -k 4,4`

Comment: sort needs to be `sort -g`