# sed: match special color characters

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I have a file containing special color encoding characters:

```
$ cat zz
aaa.gpg
bbb.gpg
ccc.gpg

$ cat -A zz
^[[38;5;216maaa.gpg^[[00m$
^[[38;5;216mbbb.gpg^[[00m$
^[[38;5;216mccc.gpg^[[00m$
```

I need to use `sed` command, to match the ending `.gpg` and remove it. So, if there were no special characters, I would use:

```
cat zz | sed 's/\.gpg$//'
```

So how can I match the `.gpg^[[00m$` pattern with `sed` ?

I tried all possible permutations, but still does not work. For example:

```
cat zz | sed 's/\.gpg\^\[\[00m$//'
```

Comment: [Remove them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14707/70524) and then use `sed`?

Comment: Do you actually want that file to contain the color encoding characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see on the terminal as `^[` is the escape character. The second `[` is a `[`.

You need to include the code for escape.

replace the `^[` with an escape character.

```
esc="$(echo '\033')"
sed 's/\.gpg'"${esc}"'\[00m$//'
```

or

```
esc='\x1b`
...
```

Comment: in sed we can use `\x1b` = esc

Comment: @JJoao - thank you. `sed 's/\.gpg\x1b\[00m$//'` is the solution I like the best.

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove ansi sequences (color and move) we can run something along the lines of

```
perl -pe 's/\e\[[0-9;]*[mGKHF]//g'
```

After that, things became much more clear...

Answer (score 3):

```
c=$(printf '\\(\33\\[[0-9;]*m\\)*')
```

Would store in `$c` a regexp that matches any number of graphic attribute setting sequences (colouring, bold, reverse video...), also known as sgr (*set graphic rendition*).

Then:

```
sed "s/${c}\.${c}g${c}p${c}g\(${c}\)\$/\5/"
```

Would remove a trailing `.gpg` including interspersed and preceding SGR sequences, but preserving trailing ones (like your `\e[00m` (sgr0) to restore default graphic rendition).

Comment: Is there some advantage in keeping the reset sequence? Say someone has a preference for a special colour (which he for example sets at the end of `$PS1`, then `cat file1 | sed "..."; cat file2` the second file will be printed with undesired colour.

Comment: @peterph, it makes sense for that `^[[38;5;216maaa.gpg^[[00m` for instance to be change to `^[[38;5;216maaa^[[00m` instead of `^[[38;5;216maaa` as the `^[[00m` was intended to terminate the `^[[38;5;216m` which we leave alone here.

Answer (score 1):

First read a bit on [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). SGR (Select Graphic Rendition - colours and similar) ends with the `m` character - so something like:

```
sed -r 's/^[\[[0-9;]*m//g'
```

should do the trick for well-behaved input. By well behaved I understand such, where the escape sequence is not interleaved by space characters (other than a space) - like `\n` or `\r`".

Note that `^[` is the escape character, not the characters `^` and `[` themselves. As for entering the escape character itself, in the a console it is easiest by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to leave the escape sequences in place, if they are already there.  You can do this:

```
sed -E 's/\.gpg([[:cntrl:]]|$)/\1/' zz
```

This will match `.gpg` followed by **either** the end of the line **or** any control character (e.g. the ESC character.).  If a control character is matched, it is preserved in the substitution with the `\1`.

If there are no escape sequences, then `.gpg` at the ends of lines will also be removed.