# How can I pipe text that contains ANSI movement characters ESC[xC and ESC[xD and output the text formatted accodingly

Tags: text-processing, ansi

I have text files that include the ANSI movement codes `ESC[xC` and `ESC[xD`.  I want to filter these out but with each line output with those codes taken into account.

Consider the line:

```
this cat is greenESC[12DdogESC[4Cwhite
```

I would like this piped out as

```
this dog is white
```

Above `ESC` means the escape code `\0x1b` (or `\033`).

Comment: Similar (my answer there would likely apply here): [How to convert escape sequences to text while preserving display format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628899)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way (and I'm sure there's better Perl), but this seems to do the trick:

```
perl -M5';$e="\x1b";' -lne 'chomp;if(/$e\[\d+[CD]/){$ns="";$p=0;while(/$e\[(\d+)([CD])/g){if(!$ns){$ns=$`;$p=length($ns)}$p+=($2eq"C"?+$1:-$1);($a=$'"'"')=~s/(^[^$e]+).*/$1/;if($a=~/^[^$e]/){substr($ns,$p,length($a),$a);$p+=length($a)}}print $ns}else{print $_}'
```

Comment: `-l` chomps already

Comment: `perl` supports `\e` for ESC (inside `"..."`, `qq(...)`, `/.../`).