# Strings comparing issue on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

this script is working properly

```
stat1=$(systemctl list-units --type=service | grep gravity | grep gcr | awk {'print $1'} | xargs systemctl status | grep Active | awk {'print $2'})
echo "$stat1"
if [ $stat1 == 'active' ]
then
  echo " >> Gravity service is running ..."
else
  echo " >> Gravity service not running ..."
fi
```

this one isn't

```
stat2=$(gravity status | grep status | awk {'print $3'})
echo "$stat2"
if [ $stat2 == 'active' ]
then
  echo " >> Gravity service is running ..."
else
  echo " >> Gravity service not running ..."
fi
```

[image: stat2 script]

the only difference between them is the input for stat variable on this script is white, and the other one is green.
i also tried using if [[  ]] , and changed '' to "" for the stat var , none of this worked
Please help me understand how to make it work.

tried this :

[image]

the result remains the same.

Comment: Side note: `[` is a command, `]` is its last argument. The command does not change the way the arguments are parsed (for comparison: it's different with `[[` which is a shell keyword). This means in general [you should double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/108618). You got away this time, still good practice is a virtue and it's way easier always to quote than to wonder each time if it's safe not to quote.

Comment: related: [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Copy and paste the relevant parts into your question

Answer (score 6):

I strongly suggest you rather use the `is-active` query from `systemctl`

```
systemctl is-active gravity
```

which returns the current service status, or:

```
sytemctl --quiet is-active gravity
```

which just exits with `0` if active and non-zero otherwise, which means you could use

```bsh
if sytemctl --quiet is-active gravity; then
  echo " >> Gravity service is running ..."
else
  echo " >> Gravity service not running ..."
fi
```

From the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

> is-active PATTERN…
>
> Check whether any of the specified units are active (i.e. running). Returns an exit code 0 if at least one is active, or non-zero otherwise. Unless --quiet is specified, this will also print the current unit state to standard output.

---

Now  for the issue itself:

Green color is passed as part of the string and thus the match fails. Compare it to this:

```
if [ "$(echo 1 | grep --color=yes 1)" = 1 ]
then echo equal
else echo different
fi
#different

if [ "$(echo 1 | grep --color=no 1)" = 1 ]
then echo equal
else echo different
fi
#equal
```

See how it is different in the first case and identical in the second one because `[ stra == strb ]` tests for *exactly* matching strings.

You could make a regex match to avoid this problem via

```
if [[ $(echo 1 | grep --color=yes 1) =~ 1 ]]
then echo equal
else echo different
fi
#equal
```

but be aware that the regex MIGHT match the color coding (not in the case of words like "active", though). Note how this needs the extended test `[[ ]]` from `bash`.

Some programs are smart enough to not forward the color to a pipe, e.g. `grep`, but one may force it:

```
echo 1 | grep 1 | cat -A
1$
echo 1 | grep 1 --color=yes | cat -A
^[[01;31m^[[K1^[[m^[[K$
```

So this is how the colorizing of `1` in bold red looks like. More on [bash colors here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting).

Comment: Hi, the systemctl output is actually working , the other one that colored green is not

Comment: Yes, just added some info on how colors are part of the string.

Comment: @Eyalu The color is in fact a set of invisible control characters that are part of the data in the string.  This means that the string can't be compared without first removing the color (or better yet, without even adding the color in the first place).

Comment: `[[ $(...) == *active* ]]` would also work (glob pattern instead of regex).