# leave color in stdout but remove from tee

Tags: text-processing, colors, tee, ansi

I want to see color output when in stdout to the console, but I want to remove it in a captured copy of the output from the `tee` command. 
In my case,

```
command_that_writes_color_to_stdout | tee file
```

I'd like the file to be clean of ANSI color sequences, etc.,
as it makes `grep`ing the log file fun later:

```
echo -e "color \033[1;31mRED\033[0m output" | tee test.log
```

In this case,
color is written to the console and also into the file "test.log".

```
color ^[[1;31mRED^[[0m output
```

Is there a way to strip ANSI sequences only for the `tee`'s output to file?

Tried to make tee see my terminal is unaware of colors (env vars, sub-shells) but `tee` happily just writes what it is given. 
I want the color for the console output (for human consumption, it's great)
but do not want color in the log file copy of the output.

```
echo -e "color \033[1;31mRED\033[0m output" | TERM=dumb tee test.log ; od -c test.log
```

I found many who *want* color codes in their "piped to tee" output (usually when the first program is aware of something being able to display color), but I'm not finding an question/answer to do the reverse.

Comment: See also [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you’re using bash, you can remove all colors (graphic renditions) with

```
echo -e "color \033[1;31mRED\033[0m output" | tee >(sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*m//g' > test.log)
```

or *all* ANSI escape sequences with

```
echo -e "color \033[1;31mRED\033[0m output" | tee >(sed $'s/\033[[][^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]//g' > test.log)
```

(I have tested this, but not exhaustively.)

P.S. If you want to append to the log file,
use `>> test.log` inside the parentheses; `tee -a` won’t do it.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, and `ansi2txt` from [colorized-logs](https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs)¹:

```
command_that_writes_color_to_stdout >&1 > >(ansi2txt > file)
```

zsh does implement a tee-like behaviour when a fd is redirected more than once for writing.

---

<sup>¹ It's available in the eponymous package on Debian/Ubuntu however note that [the algorithm is rather crude](https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs/blob/e8e889a02e0954936fdb5b4e53fe00e4e5007c33/ansi2txt.c), see [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684) for potentially finer / tighter colouring filters.</sup>