# vim remove pattern not working

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remove all occurrences of '[01;34m' from the following file:

```
Script started on 2023-09-16 10:06:45-04:00 [TERM="xterm-256color" TTY="/dev/pts/1" COLUMNS="204" LINES="55"]
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ ls^M
^[[?2004l^M^[[0m^[Desktop^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDocuments^[[0m  ^[[01;34mDownloads^[[0m  ^[[01;34mmarkdown^[[0m  ^[[01;34mMusic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mnotes^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPictures^[[0m  ^[[01;34mPublic^[[0m  ^[[01;34mscripts^[[0m  ^[[01;34msnap^[[0m  ^[[01;34mTemplates^[[0m  typescript  ^[[01;34mVideos^[[0m^M
^[[?2004h^[]0;matt@SERENITY: ~^G^[[01;32mmatt@SERENITY^[[00m:^[~^[[00m$ exit^M 
^[[?2004l^Mexit^M

Script done on 2023-09-16 10:06:49-04:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]
```

Using the command: :%s/[01;34m//g

But it's telling me it can't find the pattern, any idea why?

Comment: Related: [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)

Comment: The `[` is probably being interpreted as the opening of a regex character set, try escaping it (`\[`).