# A shell tool to “tablify” input data containing ANSI escape codes

Tags: shell, text-processing, colors, columns, tabulation

I have input containing ANSI color codes that I'd like to tablify. I want the output to remain colored, so the tablified output should maintain the ANSI color codes. Hence, naively stripping them away does not meet my requirements.

For example, for this input,

```
\033[0;32;1mgreen_apple\033[0m 1 100
orange 20 19
pineapple 1000 87
avocado 4 30
```

The output I expect would be similar to

```
green_apple 1    100
orange      20   19
pineapple   1000 87
avocado     4    30
```

In the above output, "green_apple" should be colored according to the color codes from the input i.e. green. I'd like to know how this can be accomplished.

I've tried column, but it doesn't handle ANSI codes. The output of

```
echo '\033[0;32;1mgreen_apple\033[0m 1 100
orange 20 19
pineapple 1000 87
avocado 4 30' | column -t
```

is unfortunately

```
green_apple  1     100
orange                  20    19
pineapple               1000  87
avocado                 4     30
```

Notice the non-tablification.

Comment: Do you care about the escape codes? Is it acceptable for them to be removed?

Comment: I do care about the escape codes. They should remain in the output as I want the formatted output to remain colored. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's such a command, you'd have to do by hand. Something like:

```
awk '
  {
    nf[NR]=NF
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      f[NR,i] = $i
      gsub(/\033\[[0-9;]*[mK]/, "", $i)
      len[NR,i] = l = length($i)
      if (l > max[i]) max[i] = l
    }
  }
  END {
    for (n = 1; n <= NR; n++) {
      for (i = 1; i < nf[n]; i++)
        printf "%s%*s", f[n,i], max[i]+1-len[n,i], ""
      print f[n,nf[n]]
    }
  }'
```

Comment: As per a comment and an edited question by *Jimmy Dean* (posted on the day after this answer was posted - to clarify the point), this answer now does not match the updated question's desired output which *Jimmy Dean*. states is that the *tabulated* output should show only the fruit name `green_apple` in *colour*

Comment: This is great! This has been a pain point for a while. Note that this breaks on `$(tput sgr0)` (and `$(tput -T ansi sgr0)`) which I usually use as a reset. Not sure if there's an easy fix for that. (I don't actually know how to see what `$(tput sgr0)` is actually sending.)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, I adapted this awk script from [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121139/259233).  You should be able to drop it in your `$PATH` and run it from the command line.

For example:

```
> echo -e '\e[32mHello\e[0m,World\nFoo,Bar' | colorcolumn FS=',' OFS=' | '
Hello | World
Foo   | Bar
```

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#
# colorcolumn - Like `column`, but works with ANSI colors
#
# Based on this Stack Exchange answer by Stephane Chazelas:
#     https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121139/259233

{
    nf[NR]=NF
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        cell[NR,i] = $i
        gsub(/\033\[([[:digit:]]+(;[[:digit:]]+)*)?[mK]/, "", $i)
        len[NR,i] = l = length($i)
        if (l > max[i]) max[i] = l
    }
}
END {
    for (row = 1; row <= NR; row++) {
        for (col = 1; col < nf[row]; col++)
            printf "%s%*s%s", cell[row,col], max[col]-len[row,col], "", OFS
        print cell[row,nf[row]]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of course with `column` not differentiating between printing and non-printing characters, `bash` gets around this in its prompt (`PS1`) with its `\[ \]` escape feature, I don't know of anything else that does exactly that.

I tried a quick and nasty hack, given that your problematic field is at the *start* of the line, move it to the then *end*, but you run into similar padding/alignment problems that aren't easily solved using common utilities.

```
ls -l --color | rev | column -t  | rev   # not a useful solution
```

If you have the perl `HTML::FromANSI` module install it has a useful `ansi2html` script:

```
ls -l --color | ansi2html -f
```

That only gets you halfway there, now you have to align HTML output...

There's a straightforward (though slightly heavyweight) solution with HTML as an intermediate: layout of HTML tables is effectively the thing you are trying to do.

This uses *Andre Simon*'s [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php), e.g.:

```
ls -l --color | ansifilter -fH
```

This converts ANSI sequences to HTML (`<span style="..."></span>`), then this can be dumped using a text-mode ANSI capable browser like *elinks*.

If incomplete HTML is a problem, you can optionally run [`hxclean`](http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxclean.html) or [`htmltidy`](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) to clean up the HTML before passing it to a browser.

```
ls -l --color  | ansifilter -fH | perl table.pl | elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 1
```

You should be able to use *elinks* or *w3m* [for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417376/html-to-collored-terminal-text)

The `table.pl` script splits on whitespace and adds the relevant HTML table tags to achieve the desired formatting:

```
print "<table>\n";
while (<>) { 
    print "<tr><td>" . 
      join("</td><td>", split(/((?!<[^>]+)\s+(?![^<]+>))/) ) . 
      "</td></tr>\n"; 
}
print "</table>\n";
```

It doesn't *just* split on any whitespace, it splits on whitespace that isn't inside '<' '>' angle-brackets so it doesn't break the `<span>` tag. This is not a good way to parse HTML, but it should suffice for the type of constrained input here.

You may need (I did) to set or override the default colors, either add these to your `~/.elinks/elinks.conf` file:

```
set document.colors.use_document_colors = 1
set document.colors.text = "#000000"
set document.colors.background = "#ffffff"
```

Make sure to use the latest (0.12.x) elinks, earlier versions do not support ANSI colour output.

Answer (score 0):

Some `sed` work would do the trick:

- a `sed` to remove ANSI color codes

  ```
  sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
  ```
- a `sed` to replace space(s) with tabs

  ```
  sed -r "s/\s+/\t/g"
  ```

Finaly:

```
printf "\033[0;32;1mgreen_apple\033[0m 1 100
orange 20 19
pineapple 1000 87
avocado 4 30" \
| sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" \
| sed -r "s/\s+/\t/g"
```

Output:

```
green_apple     1           100
orange          20          19
pineapple       1000        87
avocado         4           30
```

*PS*: I honestly tested all this with `ls --color output`. This is easier than playing with echo.

About removing ANSI color codes:

- From UL: [Program to strip color codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped)
- From SO: [Removing color codes with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296667/remove-ansi-color-codes-from-a-text-file-using-bash)
- another source about [removing color codes](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that fruit names contain only `_` and `alphabetic` characters.

```
c='(\e|\\033)\[[0-9;]+m'
sed -r "s/^($c)?([a-zA-Z_]+)($c)?/& \3/" file | column -t | 
sed -r "s/^($c[a-zA-Z_]+$c)( +)([a-zA-Z_]+)/\5\4\1/" |
sed -r "s/^[^ ]+ +//"
```

Output:

```
\033[0;32;1mgreen_apple\033[0m  1     100
orange       20    19
pineapple    1000  87
avocado      4     30
```

---

To (test) display the output in colour, just `printf` the *pipeline* via *shell command substiturion*, eg:

```
c='(\e|\\033)\[[0-9;]+m'; printf "$(
sed -r "s/^($c)?([a-zA-Z_]+)($c)?/& \3/;" file | column -t | 
sed -r "s/^($c[a-zA-Z_]+$c)( +)([a-zA-Z_]+)/\5\4\1/" |
sed -r "s/^[^ ]+ +//" )"
```

Output with colour – ***only*** *green_apple* shows in colour.

```
green_apple  1     100
orange       20    19
pineapple    1000  87
avocado      4     30
```